# Modular gulp / node.js, calling module variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp

Trying to call a gulp task from scripts.js with gulpfile.js, with path variables from gulpconfig.js. Starting to get lost in the dependencies

scripts.js :

```
module.exports = function(gulp, plugins) {
  return function() {
    gulp.src(srcAssets)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    };
};
```

gulpconfig.js :

```
module.exports = {
    srcAssets :  "../src/assets/js/*.js",
    dest :  "../../build",
}
```

Gulpfile.js :

```
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var config = require('./gulpconfig');
var srcAssets = config.srcAssets;
var dest = config.dest;

function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp-tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins);
}

gulp.task('scripts', getTask('prod/scripts'));
```

Result : srcAssets not defined. I don't understand, do I need to declare variables in the scripts.js module too ? That defeats the purpose of the config file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function in `scripts.js` only receives `gulp` and `plugins` as its parameters, and it has no access to `srcAssets`. The easiest solution would be to send and accept `config` as an additional parameter:

Gulpfile.js:

```
function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp-tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins, config);
}
```

scripts.js:

```
module.exports = function(gulp, plugins, config) {
  return function() {
    gulp.src(config.srcAssets)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest))
    };
};
```

Comment: sorry, srcAssets still not defined

Comment: check for typos or `console.log(config);` to confirm that it's there.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to console.log with a gulp offline file. I'm going to try and look how to do that. By the way, it worked with `exports.srcAssets = "../src/assets/";
exports.dest = "../../build";`   Can't I put them into an object ?

Comment: The code you posted above should be identical. `module.exports` IS an object.

Comment: Indeed but I'm absolutely positive it did not work with that syntax. I have no idea why. Well anyway, that's another matter I guess. Your answer helped the initial problem